# Return list of tasks from function that should be run in sequence in Airflow

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I want to return 2 or more tasks from a function that should be run in sequence in the spot they're inserted in the dependencies, see below.

```
t1 = PythonOperator()

def generate_tasks():
    t2 = PythonOperator()
    t3 = PythonOperator()
    return magic(t2, t3) # magic needed here (preferably)

t1 >> generate_tasks() # otherwise here
# desired result: t1 >> t2 >> t3
```

Is this doable? As I understand it Airflow 2.0 seems to achieve this with a TaskGroup, but we're on Google's Composer, and 2.0 won't be available for a while.

Best workaround I've found:

```
t1 = PythonOperator()

def generate_tasks():
    t2 = PythonOperator()
    t3 = PythonOperator()
    return [t2, t3]

tasks = generate_tasks()
t1 >> tasks[0] >> tasks[1]
```

But I'd really like that to be abstracted away, as it more or less defeats the purpose of having multiple operators returned from a single function. We want it to be a single unit as far as the end user knows, even though it can be composed of 2 or more tasks.

How to do it with TaskGroup in Airflow 2.0:

```
class Encryptor:
    def encrypt_and_archive(self):
        with TaskGroup("archive_and_encrypt") as section_1:
            encrypt = DummyOperator(task_id="encrypt")
            archive = BashOperator(task_id="archive", bash_command='echo 1')
            encrypt >> archive
        return section_1

with DAG(dag_id="example_return_task_group", start_date=days_ago(2), tags=["example"]) as dag:
    start = DummyOperator(task_id="start")
    encrypt_and_archive = Encryptor().encrypt_and_archive()
    end = DummyOperator(task_id='end')

             #  single variable, containing two tasks
    start >> encrypt_and_archive >> end
```

Which creates the following graph:

[image: TaskGroup in a graph]

Is something similar remotely doable before 2.0?

Comment: How about looping through the tasks?

Answer (score 5):

You didn't explain what  `magic(t2, t3)` is.
TaskGroup is strictly UI feature it doesn't effect on the DAG logic. According to your description it seems that you are looking for a specific logic (otherwise what is `magic`?).

I believe this is what you are after:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2021, 1, 24),
}
def generate_tasks():
    operator_list =[]
    for i in range(5): # Replace to generate the logic you wish to dynamically create tasks
        op = DummyOperator(task_id=f"t{str(i)}_task", dag=dag)
        if i>0:
            operator_list[i - 1] >> op
        operator_list.append(op)
    return operator_list

with DAG(
    dag_id='loop',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,
) as dag:
    start_op = DummyOperator(task_id='start_task')
    end_op = DummyOperator(task_id='end_task')
    tasks = generate_tasks()
    start_op >> tasks[0]
    tasks[-1] >> end_op
```

[image]

You can replace the DummyOperator with any operator you'd like.

Comment: This seems to achieve the same thing as my workaround as there are only 2 tasks returned from the function. Magic is just that, some yet undefined magic. We can't return them in a tuple or list, because then they'd be run in parallel, so I'm asking if I've missed any other options. I haven't tried TaskGroup out yet, but we should be able to use that for grouping dependencies as far as I can tell: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html#taskgroup

Comment: @Frans task group is just UI feature. Please add a sketch of what dependency you want between the tasks. it's very hard to understand what you are after without a proper example of the the desired output.

Comment: Updated the question with a TaskGroup example.

Comment: @Frans Your task group has only 2 hard coded operator. This create a graph with one branch which is identical to what I showed. I assume you have more complex logic (possibly with several branches in the middle?) Please show your actual expectation. If you want to show it with Task Group then show us an image of the DAG when all tasks groups are wide open (like they are not even there). Tasks group is mostly UI tweak. The logic of op >> task_group is just linking op to all heads in the task group. My answers is like task group with 1 head and 1 leaf.

Comment: @Frans If what you are really after is taking `start_op >> tasks[0]` , 
   `tasks[-1] >> end_op` and somehow create `start_op >>  X >> end_op` - This is not doable in Airflow < 2.0 for that you will have to upgrade. As I explained the functionality can be obtained but not with the same syntax.

Comment: Yes, it is. It's for hiding an "atomic" collection of tasks in a single variable/function call. An end user shouldn't just encrypt or archive, it should always be both, but at the same time we could have very novice users who could make mistakes. We also have other similar use cases. It's not necessarily important that it's displayed well in the UI, one option I considered was writing a custom operator for composing multiple arbitrary tasks into a single task, as long as it's idempotent that solution should work.

Comment: Either way, if you provide the "No, you can't" as an answer I'll reluctantly accept it. :)

Comment: @Frans You can do something with function like : `start_op >> func (object) >> end_op` Where `func(object)` defines what ever logic you wish. Example for that is the `chain` function Airflow provides https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/8723b1feb82339d7a4ba5b40a6c4d4bbb995a4f9/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L1391  But this also doest exactly as you described. Sorry have no further ideas.

Comment: @EladKalif - Can the operator in the loop be any kind of operator? I am trying to trigger multiple DAGs via TriggerDagRunOperator parsing a list. When I applied same logic as in putting the loop in a list and calling the operator I am getting following error - Object of type 'TriggerDagRunOperator' is not JSON serializable.